# How to create template and infobox in MediaWiki 1.31?

Tags: templates, mediawiki, infobox

I'm totally new to MediaWiki and I'm trying to create an Infobox that will display game informations.

I created Template:Game with:

```
{{Infobox Game
|Game Title        = {{{gameTitle}}}
|Release Date      = {{#if: {{{releaseDate}}} | {{{releaseDate}}} | N/A}}
}}
```

When I save I see:

The title of the page: Template:Game
The content is a link saying: Template:Infobox Game

Using VirtualEditor, I cannot find the template in Add a template menu.

All tutorials I find are very outdated (4yo +).

How Infobox are suppose to be created?

Thanks guys! xx

Answer (score 1):

What wiki is this on?

Not all wikis have the `Infobox Game` template, so you'll need to create it. It's just a normal template, and can have whatever you want in it. You could import it from English Wikipedia, but then you'd also need to import all of the templates and modules that it depends on, so it might be easier to just create a simple infobox template for your own purposes.